# Fetching javascript output using php

Tags: php, javascript

For example i have this code in js.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(Math.random());
</script>
```

This gives output the random number, forexample: `0.123123123123`

Now, I have fetch.php
I tried this code:

```
<?
 echo file_get_contents("js.php");
?>
```

this gives output as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(Math.random());
</script>
```

But, I want output as `0.123123123123` -- which is the output generated by javascript. I don't want the source code, but the output of that code. How can I do this using PHP?

Note: Random number is just a sample. I have something else to work on.

Comment: PHP is on the server, JavaScript is in the client.  You'd need to use an AJAX request to send the information back to the server.

Comment: Who did down vote? If you dont know the answer, pls skip. its not what your knowledge can catch.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to use JavaScript to generate a random number, rather than PHP?

Comment: @mattwhipple, oh okay, how can I do that? could you pls explain?

Comment: @PrakashTimilsina it's a big topic and a separate question.  You'll need to do research first.  I'm sure if you google using AJAX with PHP you'll find tons of tutorials.

Comment: @BenM, Did you read the Note I wrote at last of the question?

Comment: You're right. Okay. Thanks for suggestion that we can do this using ajax.

Comment: you get the -1 by me, because this question is asked regularly and has been answered numerous times already. Please understand: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a new programming question per-se.

Comment: -1 For not doing **any** *basic* research.

Answer (score 2):

JS is a different programming language, and it needs to be interpreted by a JS capable parser. You can't just fetch an HTML document with PHP and expect the JS to run, all PHP will see is text.

The two general approaches to this are:

1. Pass an HTML document to a browser over HTTP. Run the JS in the browser. Pass the data back via HTTP. (e.g. via XMLHttpRequest, or submitting a form using JS after populating a hidden input (also with JS)).
2. Pass the JS to a JS parser running on the server. e.g. using [PHP's v8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php).

Either of these approaches would require that the JS be modified; it is currently designed to add content to an HTML document. If you are using a browser, then you have to add more JS to extract it. If you are using v8 then you have to either rewrite the JS, or mock the `document` object.

You can also take an approach that is half way between the two and programatically control a browser on the server (e.g. with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)). This way you would instruct a browser to fetch the document, then you could read the DOM from it using a PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to achieve this. It is easier to do it with jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

But you can also do it with regular JavaScript:
http://linuxgazette.net/123/smith.html

Answer (score 0):

Short of using an ajax call you can't. You're trying to combine client side and server side scripting. They can't communicate without using an ajax call. The php script will run first because its server side. Therefore when the PHP runs the JavaScript random number hasn't been generated yet. The page has to load, the JavaScript has to generate the random number, and then an ajax call has to be made to the server. The number can then be used by your PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

[`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

You can execute a function on `success` callback.